# How web components communicate with each other (Lit framework)?

Tags: javascript, lit-element

So, i try to make 2 components (a nav-bar and a custom-menu) communicate with each other, knowing that the menu is not a child of the nav.
Inside the nav, I have a burger button and when i press it, i want to display the menu, but I couldnt find a way to trigger a signal in the navcomponent, so that the menu can reach it and change it`s style according to that "signal".
The only way I could make it happend was to put the menu in the nav component and work with it there, but I want to make it to be independent. Any ideas how I could make that happen? How to make 2 independent components communicate using Lit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do it is using CustomEvents. You need to dispatch the event on the window element in the hamburger `@click` method, like this:

```
<my-hamburger
@click="${() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('hamburger-clicked'));
 }">
</my-hamburger>
```

And you need of course to listen for this event in the custom menu, and you do that by using the [connectedCallback](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#add-event-listeners-in-connectedcallback) method, like this:

```
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  window.addEventListener('hamburger-clicked', this.showMenu); // here you need to pass the function responsible for showing menu
}

disconnectedCallback() {
  window.removeEventListener('hamburger-clicked', this.showMenu);
  super.disconnectedCallback();
}
```

Comment: If you stumble upon some obstacle I would recommend checking out LitElement documentation, it's pretty well made. https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the description of the code and component structure is as follows:

Navigation Container

- nav-bar
- custom-menu

nav-bar and custom-menu, both are the child components of Navigation Container.
What you can do is you need to trigger a custom event from nav-bar and listen it Navigation Container. Also you need to pass a property in custom-menu to show/hide menu, which will be changed on the basis of the custom event passed to Navigation Container from nav-bar.

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit-element';


// your Navigation Continer
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      showHideMenu: {type: Boolean}, //property to be send in menu component
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.showHideMenu = false;
  }
  
  _handleShowHide(e){
  // change showHideMenu property on the basis of recieved value
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <nav-bar
      @handleShowHideEvent="${this._handleShowHide}"
      >
      </nav-bar>
      <menu
      .showhide=${this.showHideMenu}
      ></menu>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

You can refer above code, though there is more to be done apart from this. Like you need to dispatch and **handleShowHideEvent** event nav-bar (on your menu click) and also you need to read the **showhide** property in your menu component.